# Where to find the google play's viewpagerindicator?

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

[image]

I want the same viewpagerindicator effect as google play did, but it is not included in JakeWharton's repo(https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/releases). Where can I or how can I achieve this kind of indicator, thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a similar one on github
https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip